# Jenkins job executed on kubernetes cluster runs on jnlp image instead of specified one

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins

I have a situation I don't quite understand. It seems like my code is executed in the wrong image - even though the log states that it has loaded my image.

### Expected output vs actual

When I run `docker run -it jstevnsvig/jenkins-build-slave-php:v8.2 /bin/sh -c "dpkg-query -l | cat"` I get the expected output.
When I run a Jenkins freestyle job with the appropriate tag, with a single script step executing `dpkg-query -l | cat` I get what I assume is the output from running in the jnlp image (`jenkins/inbound-agent:3077.vd69cf116da_6f-3-jdk11`)
How do I get it to run on the correct image?

[image: docker vs k8s]

### Jenkins Kubernetes cloud Pod template Configuration

[image: Jenkins configuration]

### Jenkins job console

```yaml
Started by user JoSSte
Running as SYSTEM
Agent php8-2dfd8 is provisioned from template php8
---
apiVersion: "v1"
kind: "Pod"
metadata:
  labels:
    jenkins: "slave"
    jenkins/label-digest: "cb0616020c016c081bd72366740b4151da57f6a3"
    jenkins/label: "php8"
  name: "php8-2dfd8"
  namespace: "devops-tools"
spec:
  containers:
  - args:
    - "9999999"
    command:
    - "sleep"
    image: "jstevnsvig/jenkins-build-slave-php:v8.2"
    imagePullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"
    name: "php8t"
    resources: {}
    tty: false
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: "/home/jenkins/agent"
      name: "workspace-volume"
      readOnly: false
    workingDir: "/home/jenkins/agent"
  - env:
    - name: "JENKINS_PROTOCOLS"
      value: "JNLP4-connect"
    - name: "JENKINS_SECRET"
      value: "********"
    - name: "JENKINS_AGENT_NAME"
      value: "php8-2dfd8"
    - name: "JENKINS_DIRECT_CONNECTION"
      value: "jenkins-service:50000"
    - name: "JENKINS_INSTANCE_IDENTITY"
      value: "..."
    - name: "JENKINS_NAME"
      value: "php8-2dfd8"
    - name: "JENKINS_AGENT_WORKDIR"
      value: "/home/jenkins/agent"
    image: "jenkins/inbound-agent:3077.vd69cf116da_6f-3-jdk11"
    name: "jnlp"
    resources:
      requests:
        memory: "256Mi"
        cpu: "100m"
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: "/home/jenkins/agent"
      name: "workspace-volume"
      readOnly: false
  hostNetwork: false
  nodeSelector:
    kubernetes.io/os: "linux"
  restartPolicy: "Never"
  volumes:
  - emptyDir:
      medium: ""
    name: "workspace-volume"
```

I have tried changing the label of the container template to `jnlp` but then it doesn't connect properly (my image is built on the jenkins/agent image)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As documented [here](https://plugins.jenkins.io/kubernetes/#plugin-content-using-the-pipeline-step), by default, commands in Jenkins agents will run in the `jnlp` container. If you want to have them run in another container, that you have defined in the `podTemplate`, you use the `container {..}` block (section [here](https://plugins.jenkins.io/kubernetes/#plugin-content-multiple-containers-support))

```
podTemplate(containers: [
    containerTemplate(name: 'maven', image: 'maven:3.8.1-jdk-8', command: 'sleep', args: '99d'),
    containerTemplate(name: 'golang', image: 'golang:1.16.5', command: 'sleep', args: '99d')
  ]) {

    node(POD_LABEL) {
        stage('Get a Maven project') {
            git 'https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-plugin.git'
            container('maven') {
                stage('Build a Maven project') {
                    sh 'mvn -B -ntp clean install'
                }
            }
        }
...
```

Comment: so if I extend the `jenkins/inbound-agent:3077.vd69cf116da_6f-3-jdk11` container instead of `jenkins/agent` and label it jnlp it should work as well?

Comment: Provided that inbound agent is successfully able to connect to the jenkins master node, yes.

Comment: @BlenderFox how do you make the job to run another container by default without the fact that you need to change every job to use container('container_name') section. Is there a way to do it in the Jenkins configuration?

Comment: @EilonA Jenkins will run its actions in the jnlp container by default unless you tell it otherwise. The alternative if you don't want to do this is for you to extend the jnlp container and configure it with your tools, then use that in place of the jnlp image, but then you need to remember to rebuild it often or you will lose any features and fixes in the later jnlp image versions.

Comment: @BlenderFox how do I combine them? If my base image already has FROM another image?

My image -
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN "apt-get blabla"

How do I combine it with the jenkins/inbound-agent image? I can't use multiple form unless I copy artifacts no? which artifact should I take?

Comment: I have opened a new question here -
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75572075/im-using-jenkins-with-kubernetes-plugin-and-i-want-to-combine-jnlp-image-with-m